# error: cannot find symbol - working with file scanner loops

Tags: java, file, input

What does this error mean? On every line of the code below the try catch block this error occurs. I'm confused as to why this error keeps appearing.

My imports:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
```

My method:

```
public static void readLists(ArrayList <String> list1, ArrayList <String> list2)


      {
 Scanner list1s;
Scanner list2s;

      try
      {
        list1s = new Scanner(new File("list1.txt"));
        list2s = new Scanner(new File ("list2.txt"));
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
      {
        System.out.println("File not found!\n");
      }

      while(list1s.hasNext())
        list1.add(list1s.next());

      while(list2s.hasNext())
        list2.add(list2s.next());

      list1s.close();
      list2s.close();

    }
```

Updated code was from the suggestions in the comments. However, I get the following error:  variable list1s might not have been initialized
      while(list1s.hasNext())

If I do not have the scanner declaration and initialization in the try/catch. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Just declare `Scanner list1s` (and `list2s`) _before_ the start of the `try` block.

Comment: Why did you change the code?  You have fixed the problem; are you saying you still have a problem?

Comment: What do you expect your code to do if there was an error reading the file?

Comment: @shmosel I am going to be adding more features later. I need to understand the initial reading of the file first  and then I'm going to finish up all the other pieces like if there is an error and such.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. It now says Lab01.java:38: error: variable list1s might not have been initialized
      while(list1s.hasNext())
            ^
Lab01.java:42: error: variable list2s might not have been initialized
      while(list2s.hasNext())

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to use your scanners when they may not have been created. You need to decide what to do if there's an error. One option is to move the loops into the `try` so they only run if no error was thrown.

Comment: @shmosel Thank you, that was clearer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static Scanner list1s;
static  Scanner list2s;
public static void readLists(ArrayList <String> list1, ArrayList <String> list2)

{

    try
    {
        list1s = new Scanner(new File("list1.txt"));
        list2s = new Scanner(new File ("list2.txt"));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found!\n");
    }
// Your code
}
```

**Just for reference:** class and instance variables when declared, are automatically given their default values.

Comment: I updated my post with the code with this suggestion, however, it then says they are not initialized. I'm confused.

Comment: And there is no use of the `File file1, file2` also. They have been deleted :)

Comment: Oh, that makes sense as to where my error was coming from. I was declaring them above the try and not outside of the method. Thank you!